# Degree of a non-surjective map f

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In my notes I found an excercise claiming that $f: S^n \to S^n$ has $deg(f)=0$ whenever it's not surjective. I can prove this if I assume smoothness by applying Sard's theorem but I'm wondering if this is true without smoothness? Maybe I just forgot to write down this additional condition, but I can't come up with a counterexample.

Comment: I like the answer below, but one can often get away by assuming smoothness in these questions. The reason is that a continuous map can be approximated arbitrarily by a smooth one, i.e. it is homotopic to one. In this question the point is to show that a continuous map that misses a point can be approximated by a smooth one that misses a point. One uses compactness of the domain for this.

Comment: how do you prove it with sard thm (out of curiosity)

Comment: @cesareborgia I think that Sard is not even necessary as values that are not obtained are regular by definition. So for instance by using the local degree formula you get an empty sum which then is trivially $0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is not surjective, it factors over the sphere minus a point, which is contractible. Consequently, the map is null homotopic and hence has degree zero.

Comment: Wow that was really easy. My approach is a ridiculous overkill compared to this much easier and more general solution, thank you very much!